# C# Methods with infinite parameters array access

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

After learning how to [Create a method with infinite parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435757/creating-methods-with-infinite-parameters), I wonder is it legal to store the parameter array into a array. Will it cause any problem, since I don't see many people use this approach.

Code below :

```
class Foo
{
    private String[] Strings;

    public Foo(params String[] strings)
    {
        Strings = strings;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Side note: it's not infinite -- an array has a max size of `int.MaxValue`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's fine - it's just an array.

All the compiler does with a parameter array is convert a call like this:

```
Foo("x", "y");
```

into:

```
Foo(new string[] { "x", "y" });
```

That's really all there is to it. Anything you'd expect to be appropriate with the second call is fine with a parameter array.

Arrays passed into public methods are rarely suitable to store directly due to all arrays being mutable - but that's a matter of how you handle mutable parameter types rather than being specific to parameter arrays.