# Can an object of a class take multiple values (like an array)

Tags: c#, oop

If I have a constructor with an array like:

```
public Courses(string courseName, string courseCode, string passingGrade, string numOfCredits, string[] prerequisites)
```

The array prerequisites is supposed to take whatever prerequisite that a course has, which may be more than one, if I create an object in my main class, how do I add multiple values to it?

```
Courses courses = new Courses(Computer Science, CS50, C+, 3, this is the array prerequisites, how could I add multiple strings here? )
```

Comment: Duplicate of [All possible array initialization syntaxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678216/all-possible-array-initialization-syntaxes) and/or [Creating methods with infinite parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2435757/8967612)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `params` keyword in your constructor signature like so:

```cs
public Courses(string courseName, string courseCode, string passingGrade, string numOfCredits, params string[] prerequisites)
```

More on the `params` keyword here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params

Note that the example of your constructor call is malformed. It should look like this to use strings:

```cs
Courses courses = new Courses("Computer Science", "CS50", "C+", "3", "this is the array prerequisites", "how could I add multiple strings here?");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there are two ways of doing this. Firstly you can use the constructor you just defined

```
public Courses(string courseName, string courseCode, string passingGrade, string numOfCredits, string[] prerequisites)
```

And when passing the arguments just pass an array as the argument.

```
var course = new Courses("Abc", "157", "100", "4", new string[] {"ABC", "def ", "abcdef"});
```

or you can use the `params` keyword to have the array as comma separated strings.

```
public Courses(string courseName, string courseCode, string passingGrade, string numOfCredits, params string[] prerequisites)
```

Which you can call like

```
var course = new Courses("Abc", "157", "100", "4", "ABC", "def", "abcdef");
```

Comment: Ah yes, this allows me to do what's expected.